# Why do I have to create a new iCloud password every day since upgrading my computer?

Tags: icloud, password

Since getting my new MacBook Air it requires me to create a new password every day for iCloud.  It first asks for my password because "some account services will not be available until you sign in again".  I never signed out.

When I enter my password it says that it is the wrong password.  I then reset it to the exact same password I was using and it accepts it as a new password ant tells me that my password has been reset.  Tomorrow, I will have to do this all over again.  This can't be normal.

Comment: It for sure isn't (normal). What happens if you change the password, sign in and then directly sign out again, and then try to sign in  a second time?

Comment: Well I've n ever signed out of iCloud ever.  When I try it asks me if I want to keep copies of data on iCloud to this computer.  Yes or no?  Is there a risk of loosing iCloud content?

Comment: There may be a risk, so let's not follow that idea for now.

Comment: I just signed in to iCloud with my phone.  It accepted the NEW password ok.  Should I have to sign in with each device individually when they are already linked and connected to iCloud?

Comment: Not sure I understand how you sign in on a phone if it is already connected to iCloud (which implies signin).

Comment: I don't understand it either.  My phone and both computers require that I sign in again every day  and once I change my password so I can do that, the other devices still tell me to sign in, which I do with the new password.  This all started a week ago when I bought this new Air.

Comment: Since this occurred when you got your new Air, it might be an issue with the user ID and how you authenticate.  Try disconnecting iCloud from the new account, ensure it works properly on your old devices, the add a new user on your new Air  and connect to iCloud.

Comment: What should I do when It asks if I want to keep data from iCloud on my computer?  Is there a risk of losing my cloud data?   when You say disconnect from account do mean remove the device from iCloud?

Comment: Yes, remove your new Air from iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

You should first use https://appleid.apple.com to verify your password works properly.

If you receive the following popup, offering to use your fingerprint, click "Use a different Apple ID" (even if it shows the correct one) so that you can enter your password:

[image: SIWA Prompt]

Once you've verified you can sign in and that there are no error messages on https://appleid.apple.com, note exactly what password it is (write it down if you have to) and **do not change the password again, to avoid confusion**.

Sign out of whichever device is giving the most frequent errors. It sounds like this is your MacBook Air.

Fully sign out of iCloud and restart the Mac, then sign back in.

At this point, your Mac should be behaving properly. If it is not, come back here and indicate exactly what steps you took and what it's telling you.

If it's working properly, repeat the process at signing out of iCloud on any other devices that aren't working properly.

Comment: @Kendu Does it still work on appleid.apple.com?

Comment: Yes, no problem

Comment: I just contacted Apple.  The first thing they want me to do is to see if the problem resolves when I'm not on wifi to determine if that may be what's causing this.  I'll test it tomorrow when the issue occurs again.

Comment: I wonder if it could also have something to do with your Date & Time. Are they all set properly?

Comment: Yes, Date and time are ok